# Unable to view full picture in Internet Explorer

Tags: lumia

Whenever i open few sites in IE it doesn't show full picture, for example this site itself "http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com".This is how it shows [image]

I know this question was already asked but that was i guess facebook issues but i am facing this issue on some other websites too.
I am using lumia 620 (windows 8.1 developer preview)

Comment: I think it simply has to do with the website being designed badly by not keeping IE for WP in mind when designing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If images do not scale properly for your mobile device you either have set the Internet Explorer to show the desktop version (which you can change in the settings) or it's an issue the developer of the site has to address.

In the case you posted above the image doesn't show up for me properly as well, so I don't think there's something to be done.

Comment: I haven't set the desktop version, its set to mobile version.

Comment: Then this is an issue the web developer has to fix.